# CSS - Variations of DIV settings?

Tags: css

I am using the same CSS sheet for all the html pages on our website.

This is the CSS container:

```
    #Container {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    border-color: #CCC;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    }
```

This is fine on all the pages except one, which needs the height to be 1000px.

How would I make a variation of the code for one page, instead of copying the entire container settings again for the one html page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the page in question give the body a class e.g. 'myPage' then add the below to your css

```
body.mypage  #container{
    height:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. The page is still only 600px high. `<div id="Container" class="services">` `body.services #Container {
 height: 1000px; 
}`

Comment: @user3012826 I'd erroneously written width instead of height, have you tried height (edited above)? Also, has your body tag on that page got any other classes attached to it?

Comment: Yep I noticed that. I used height though.

Comment: @user3012826 In the code in your comment you're putting the services class on the container div, not on the body element of the page, you either need to do <body class='services'> or alternatively change your CSS to #container.services{...

Comment: Ah ok. I see now! The top level is the one that has the higher importance. Thanks!